# What is written in this satellite photograph? (Characters identified: 忠于毛主席)

Tags: translation, character-identification

What is written in Chinese at this location `40.449787, 116.548828` on Google maps?

Tried using translators. But didn't find any feasible answer for this.

[image: This is the image]

I used Google translator and wrote these words 于 毛 王 床 and got this translation - Yu Mao king bed.

Comment: What's the input you submitted to the translator?

Comment: I used Google translator and wrote these words 于 毛 王 床 and got this translation - 

Yu Mao king bed

Comment: you forgot the 忠 - although a nice Yu Mao King Bed would be nice...

Comment: I just went there 2 months ago. The slogan reminds me of the fanatical time.

Comment: Sorry but I could not stop laughing...

Comment: [Another good answer in another post](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/17575/2816).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The characters read:

```
忠于毛主席
Zhōng yú Máo zhǔxí
```

- 忠 means faithful;
- 于 is a multi-use preposition which, to me, sounds a bit archaic/formal, and here means "to", but can also mean "in" or "on";
- 毛 is Mao Zedong's surname;
- 主席 means "chairman".

So this translates to "Faithful to Chairman Mao". By the way, if you give the correct characters to Google, the translation it gives is `Loyal to Chairman Mao`.

Answer (score 6):

This means we are loyal to Chairman Mao.

Comment: It's not 于毛王床，it's 忠于毛主席

Comment: user6269 is right. Answer seems to be wrong.